# Creating a console window from a WinAPI window?

Tags: c++, winapi, mingw, codeblocks

Well, I have a project to do and would like some help. My purpose for the project is to create a console window when the user presses the "Start" button on a WinAPI window. I don't want the window to show upon startup. What do I need to put in the `WM_COMMAND` case to create a console window when the "Start" button is pressed?

I'm using WinAPI (C++) & Code::Blocks with MinGW.

Answer (score 1):

[`AllocConsole`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

It is important to master the art of [*reading the documentation*](ftp://rtfm.mit.edu/).

Browse around in MSDN Library to get familiar with it.

Try to find things, e.g., I suggest try to find `WScript.Echo`.

For example.

Comment: So how do I output text to the console?

Comment: @Mike: if you have tried this and not managed to output text to the console, then I suggest asking a new SO question about that and including a *complete* but minimal example that demonstrates the problem.